# Javascript Project: Counter - Why colors don't want to work?

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner at javascript so what I'm going to ask is probably very trivial. I made a small project, a counter. Here's the codepen for the project:
https://codepen.io/pipepanna/pen/zYwMzaR?editors=0010

```js
const decreaseBtn = document.querySelector(".decrease");
const increaseBtn = document.querySelector(".increase");
const resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset");
const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");

let count = 0;

decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count--;
  counter.textContent = count;
});

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count++;
  counter.textContent = count;
});

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count = 0;
  counter.textContent = count;
});

if (count > 0) {
  counter.style.color = "green";
} else if (count < 0) {
  counter.style.color = "red";
} else {
  counter.style.color = "black";
}
```

There's a working solution as well, but below there's one where colours just don't want to switch. I wrote a separate little function for each button for decreasing, increasing and resetting the counter so the problem probably lies there. I just thought that I declared the "count" variable globally and so its value will be updated with each click and so it will also change the colour as it goes below/above 0. This proved to be faulty logic, I'm just curious, why. Can anyone please explain what I'm missing here? As I said, I'm a complete newbie, so this might be something really obvious ^^

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code will be executed only once, when all counters are 0. It will not react when counter will change.

```
if (count > 0) {
  counter.style.color = "green";
} else if (count < 0) {
  counter.style.color = "red";
} else {
  counter.style.color = "black";
}
```

To achive this you may use callback technique, like this:

```js
const decreaseBtn = document.querySelector(".decrease");
const increaseBtn = document.querySelector(".increase");
const resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset");
const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");

let count = 0;

decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count--;
  counter.textContent = count;
  onCount();
});

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count++;
  counter.textContent = count;
  onCount();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count = 0;
  counter.textContent = count;
  onCount();
});

function onCount() {
  if (count > 0) {
    counter.style.color = "green";
  } else if (count < 0) {
    counter.style.color = "red";
  } else {
    counter.style.color = "black";
  }

}
```

```html
<span class="counter"></span>
<button class="increase" type="button">Increase</button>
<button class="decrease" type="button">Decrease</button>
<button class="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just that this code:

```
if (count > 0) {
  counter.style.color = "green";
} else if (count < 0) {
  counter.style.color = "red";
} else {
  counter.style.color = "black";
}
```

Is only run once, when the page first loads - and as this is the only place where you update the color, the color will never change on click. All your click event listeners do is update the `count` variable and set the counter's text content do it - they don't do anything with the color.

You just need to put this in a function that you call from inside each event handler. Eg like this:

```
const resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset");
const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");

let count = 0;

decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count--;
  counter.textContent = count;
  updateColor();
});

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count++;
  counter.textContent = count;
  updateColor();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count = 0;
  counter.textContent = count;
  updateColor();
});

function updateColor() {
  if (count > 0) {
    counter.style.color = "green";
  } else if (count < 0) {
    counter.style.color = "red";
  } else {
    counter.style.color = "black";
  }
}
```

You could also put the `counter.textContent = count` inside the function too if you wanted, as this is also repeated for each click action.